# A great stereo shotgun mic.

Tags: stereo, shotgun

Im looking for a great stereo shotgun mic within the $1,000-$2,000 range. What can you suggest?

Comment:   
 Pearl MSH 10 or MSH 20 (http://www.pearlmicrophones.com/index.php/products/microphones-by-type/shotgun/msh10andmsh20-detail). Both under $2000 in Europe at least (http://www.sfb.net/acatalog/Pearl_Microphones.html).

Comment: It seems that the older MSH 10 and MSH 20 (they look like the older models) are available as (presumably) cheaper models MS2 and MS8 as well: http://www.independentaudio.com/index.php?main_page=index&manufacturers_id=11&sort=20a&filter_id=41

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a ton of options out there. The few that come to mind are the [Audio-Technica AT835ST](http://www.audio-technica.com/cms/wired_mics/b92dc794916f0fa7/index.html) (right around $1k), [Sanken CSS-5](http://www.sanken-mic.com/en/product/product.cfm/9.1001600) ($2300), and the [Sennheiser MKH418S](http://en-us.sennheiser.com/stereo-shotgun-microphone-condenser-mkh-418-s) ($1700). The Audio-Technica can be used in either M/S or XY mode (it's outputting a decoded M/S signal, not true XY) and the Sanken has multiple modes as well. The Sennheiser is M/S only. I haven't used the AT or Sanken personally, but I know a few people who like both microphones. The Sennheiser isn't bad (we have one at work), but it can be noisy and is never my first choice as far as stereo recordings.

From what I've heard, the AT and the Sanken have similar noise floors. So, that's something to keep in mind regarding use and application. Is there a particular reason you want a "shotgun" style microphone? Would any "single point stereo" mic do, or are you specifically looking for something with an interference tube?

Comment: The MKH418S at least is quite noisy mic.

Answer (score 0):

What is the intended use? Shotgun implies you want an MS setup.
XY is not possible with a shotgun mic, unless you use 2, but it won't sound great.